# Using SASS Variables on WordPress Customizer

Tags: wordpress, sass

Is it possible to use `$variable` on WordPress customizer? Does anyone has any example of how it should be properly done.

Basically, what I need is an option to change `&primary-color` and `&text-link-color` via the 'customize' panel.

Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: For simple cases, you can use token values and replace them in css.

Comment: Hi, do you mind if you could elaborate? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example, if you need to dynamically change `text-link-color`, you can create variable in sass with some reserved value that will be used as a marker for `text-link-color`, it might be invalid color value, just some specific value that you won't actually use. Then assign this variable to all things that will have same color as `text-link-color`. After it you can easily find(with simple script) those token values inside the css and replace them with actual colors.